# jquery form submit not triggered when passing event data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to submit a form with event data on click of a button. I have following jquery code to fire the event. But it's not getting triggered.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#button1,#button2').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('form#form1').submit({
      "url": "url"
    }, doSomethint);
  });

  function doSomethint(e) {
    var url = ev.data.url;
    alert(url);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="button1">Button1</button>
<button type="submit" id="button2">Button2</button>

<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" value="123">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1bdesjof/

Comment: Have you tried simply doing `$("#form").submit()`?

Comment: @JackBashford, I am trying to send the URL as event data along with form submit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the submit buttons are not in the form tag and the variable ev was undefined.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#button1,#button2').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('form#form1').submit({
      "url": "url"
    }, doSomethint);
  });

  function doSomethint(ev) {
    var url = ev.data.url;
    alert(url);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
<button type="submit" id="button1">Button1</button>
<button type="submit" id="button2">Button2</button><br/>
  <input type="text" value="123">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference:

`$('#form1').submit()` it will submit the form

`$('#form1').submit(eventData, handler)` add event to the form

because your submit button outside the `form` there is no `submit` event called. Solution, add your button to the form container or call `$('#form1').submit()` after add event like below.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#button1,#button2').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('#form1').submit({
      "url": "url"
    }, doSomethint);
    // call it
    $('#form1').submit()
  });

  function doSomethint(ev) {
    var url = ev.data.url;
    alert(url);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="button1">Button1</button>
<button type="submit" id="button2">Button2</button>

<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" value="123">
</form>
```